# How to get a specific value using python requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse this site https://www.5dimes.eu/ and extract a specific value from it. as shown in the figure but it is not at all the getting populated with the get request. But I am able to see it when I open the browser.
[image]

I am just getting the output as shown below.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
t = requests.get("https://www.5dimes.eu/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(t.content)
print(soup.find_all('td'))


<td align="center" colspan="3"><input class="login" id="customerID" maxlength="50" name="customerID" type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="middle">
<td align="center" colspan="3" height="20" valign="bottom">Password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" height="1"><img alt="5Dimes Sportsbook - Casino - Racebook - Lottery - Poker" border="0" height="1" src="images/trans.gif" title="5Dimes Sportsbook - Casino - Racebook - Lottery - Poker" width="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="middle">
<td align="center" colspan="3"><input autocomplete="off" class="login" maxlength="50" name="password" type="password"/>
<input id="ioBB" name="ioBB" type="hidden"/>
</td>
```

Comment: The browser runs JavaScript. `requests` doesn’t. The `ioBB` field is populated by JavaScript.

Comment: @Boldewyn I am new to JavaScript. But with the get method we are able to see the id name and type but it is not getting in the value part alone if we have to login to the site we should need that as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.5dimes.eu/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

val = soup.find("input", {'id': 'ioBB'}).get("value")

print(val)
driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: is selenium the only option I am trying to get this through requests. will it be possible?

Comment: @ankushreddy so you have to use `PHANTOMJS` or any module which can render `JS`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using requests_html.

Here is the code.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get("https://www.5dimes.eu/", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
r.html.render()
print(r.html.html)
```

Comment: be informed that `requests_html` is supporting Unix only.